# ContentControl and CollectionView.CurrentItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Referencing this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-a-collection-and-display-information-based-on-selection

(some relevant code snippets:)

```
<Window.Resources>

<local:People x:Key="MyFriends"></local:People>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DetailTemplate">
  <Border Width="300" Height="100" Margin="20"
          BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="1" Padding="8">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="First Name:"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Last Name:"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Home Town:"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=HomeTown}"/>
    </Grid>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<ListBox Width="200" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyFriends}}"/>

<ContentControl x:Name="contentControl1"
  Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyFriends}}"
  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DetailTemplate}" />
```

Both `ListBox.ItemsSource` and `ContentControl.Content` bind to the same source (`MyFriends`, an instance of the People class which derives from `ObservableCollection<Person>`). If my understanding is correct, this means that both the `ListBox.ItemsSource` and `ContentControl.Content` properties will be bound to the same implicitly created instance of `ListCollectionView`.

I understand that setting `ListBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` synchronizes `ListBox.SelectedItem` and `ItemCollection.CurrentItem`.

`DetailTemplate` (above) displays the details of the selected `ListBox` item, despite being 'bound' to a ListCollectionView. Specifying `Path=/` (what I thought would be necessary to achieve the resulting behavior) does not have any effect - it's as if WPF knows to do it implicitly somehow:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="contentControl1"
  Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyFriends}, Path=/}"
  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DetailTemplate}" />
```

As a test, I created another `ContentControl` with `Content` bound to a `DataTemplate` containing a `ListBox`:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="contentControl2"
  Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyFriends}}"
  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DetailTemplate2}" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="DetailTemplate2">
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"></>
</DataTemplate>
```

And it displayed the list.

My question is: Why does `DataTemplate` get the selected `Person` object while the `ListBox` and `DetailTemplate2` get the `People` collection?

(the behavior is desirable, I just don't understand what black magic is occurring under the hood to make it so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a good question! I didn't notice that until read your post. So, after did some digging from source code of `PropertyPathWorker`, it appears that when `PropertyPathWorker` failed to solve a member of an object, in your case, it try to solve 'FirstName', 'LastName' ect. with 'MyFriends', it will try to solve it with the view of the object. And if still failed, it will try to solve it with view's `CurrentItem`, and that's where the magic happened. You can find those codes in `PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(int k, ICollectionView collectionView, object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)` and `PropertyPathWorker.ReplaceItem(int k, object newO, object parent)`.

Comment: Nice detective work! That's interesting that it "looks around" for the best fit of what to bind to. I keep forgetting that the source is available (and even if I didn't I probably wouldn't have known where to look).

Comment: @Shea I am also happy to learn some new things. In fact, WPF data binding engine is a lot more complicate than people thought.